I need to cook for a group of around 500 people for a week. I have a rough plan, what am I missing?
I want to preface this with the fact that I have 8 kids, and we enjoy making use of leftovers normally, meaning the meals I cook every day usually either fill up a 2 gallon or 3 gallon pot, and cooking for family get togethers before I've filled up my 8 gallon pot preparing for plenty of food. The point here being I'm used to cooking for large groups, not that I necessarily have the experience for cooking for massive groups. Someone recently asked me if I could cook meals for a large gathering of around 500 people. I have a rough plan to make soups, curries and chilis by expanding the recipes I already make to the 8 gallon pot size. I should also point out I will only have access to 4 double burner propane stoves, so no ovens, and I won't be able to do any pre-cooking necessarily since the group size is so large and the event is a week long, it will all have to be done on the propane stoves. I also have 8 8 gallon pots available. Suggestions for other meal types, and suggestions for ways to make prep much quicker? I already have 3 commercial vegetable choppers, a large capacity scale I use for weighing ingredients, and 8 8 gallon pots.
Edit: Thanks for the feedback, several good points brought up that I'll give some serious thought to. To answer a few questions:
This will be a week long event and will be outside (think tent camping) and isn't so much of a catered event if you will, as it is "Here is food we are providing that you can eat if you wish", so I guess not so much worried about allergies, although my recipes are all diary, gluten and soy free anyways. While some things could be prepped the night before, I'm thinking the easiest things to stick to for this many people is generally going to be soup, chili and curry. For those meals, food could just be kept hot on the stove until it was either put away or finished off. I'll probably have several different shifts for meals to keep things organized and more manageable.
I can feed around 55-65 people from one 8 gallon pot, and I have 8 8 gallon pots, which gets me pretty close. I have 4 propane stoves, enough to fit all 8 pots at the same time.

What help do you have available to chop, stir etc.?

I'll have a group of people to help me, and I can recruit more people if needed. I have a supply of 18" stirring spoons and wood spoons as well as 3 of these: https://www.webstaurantstore.com/choice-3-8-french-fry-cutter-potato-cutter/40747713.html?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&gclid=Cj0KCQjwveK4BhD4ARIsAKy6pMIBu3jZd6Iak-rLKsZG5c4iOJPfIMzMdDs-E9FUXdfBEBBMrInQv2gaAnD5EALw_wcB

You say you can't pre-cook, but is pre-cutting and pre-paring (weighing/measuring ) an option? Or does that have to happen on-site too? How many people do you usually feed from 1 8 gallon pot, and how many is 'a handful', enough to hold 500 servings of anything or will you have to keep cooking while you're serving to be able to have enough food? Do you have information from the person planning this, like wishes with regards to meals, dietary restrictions (vegetarian, vegan, kosher, halal?), allergies, will these 500 people arrive all at once as one hungry horde or in smaller groups?

World Central Kitchen put out a cookbook last year that has some tips on what you should do when scaling recipes, but I was really surprised that all of the recipes in the cookbook only served 4-8 people:  https://wck.org/cookbook

Sorry, we don't take "tips and tricks" types of question. This is terribly broad. In this sense, we are no different from Stack Overflow - questions have to be about a concrete problem you're facing, not a "please tell me everything about X" thing.

I should preface this by saying this isn't an answer per se but rather a comment that's too long for a single comment.
I think you should give some serious thought as to whether you're biting off more that you can chew. I think it goes without saying that there's a big difference between cooking for 5 people (5 for the sake of argument), and 500 people but do you really understand how big of a difference?

The things I've come up with on my own are just expanding the recipes
I already make to the 8 gallon pot size.

So X times the amount of ingredients but what about preparation time? Does chopping 100 onions take just 10x longer than chopping 10 or does chopping the last 10 of the 100, take twice as long as the first 10? How much extra physical space will you need for prep? Will you have a great big pile of onions on the chopping board or do you have somewhere safe and hygienic to store ingredients before they're cooked? What about meat?... How long will that chicken be sitting out on the work area, whilst it's being chopped up? Will you have to prep all the ingredients before you start cooking because you won't have time to chop as you go?... Does cooking 10x the normal quantity of one of your recipes mean that it will take twice as long to actually cook? Or will it take 5x as long? How early will you and your crew have to start?

I should also point out I will only have access to several propane stoves, so no ovens, and I
won't be able to do any pre-cooking, it will all have to be done on
the propane stoves.

Are the propane stoves of a high enough capacity to cook for that many people? Do you have enough of the stoves to cook the meals and keep them warm at the same time?
Which highlights perhaps the most important issue... do you know how to safely cook for that many people? If you're serving anything that's not hot, how will you keep it safe to eat? Not to mention allergies. I don't want to be a downer but you really need to think about safety when so many people are placing their well-being in your hands. And that's what they're doing... if you're the one overseeing the operation, then it's your responsibility (not least in a legal sense) that someone doesn't end up getting food poisoning or worse.
The list of questions goes on but my main point is, how much thought have you given the reality of what you're contemplating, given that you've never cooked for that many people? How many of these questions have you asked yourself?
I'm not saying you can't do it, or even that you shouldn't. I'm just saying that you need to know what you're biting off.

yeah... I don't know that I've cooked for more than 200 people at once, and for those it was generally 6-12 people (none of us professionals) doing the prep and cooking.   And that still took a LOT of planning (and access to a walk-in-fridge so we could do prep the night before)

These are excellent points you bring up, I'll have to give these points some serious consideration. Thank you!
